# Error while Deserializing in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to deserialize a code and I keep getting an error in one of my try-catch statements.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class CalendarChecker
{

public static void main( String[] args )
{

    Event party = null;
    Event test = null;

    ObjectInputStream input = null; 

    try{
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myFile.txt"));
    }
    catch {
        party = (Event)input.readObject();
        test = (Event)input.readObject();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        input.readObject();
        input.readObject();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        input.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    System.out.println( party.getName() );
    System.out.println( party.getDate() );
    System.out.println( party.getLocation() );
    System.out.println( party.getDescription() );
    System.out.println( test.getName() );
    System.out.println( test.getDate() );
    System.out.println( test.getLocation() );
    System.out.println( test.getDescription() );

}


}
```

Whenever I go to compile it, this is the error I get:

```
CalendarChecker.java:19: error: '(' expected
        catch {
             ^
CalendarChecker.java:19: error: illegal start of type
        catch {
              ^
CalendarChecker.java:20: error: ')' expected
            party = (Event)input.readObject();
                 ^
CalendarChecker.java:20: error: not a statement
            party = (Event)input.readObject();
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't write code like this. It's pointless. Code that depends on the success of prior code in a `try` block should be inside that `try` block. You only need one `try/catch` here, maybe another one in a `finally` block to ensure the closes.

Comment: where did you see code written like this that made you think this was a good idea or idiom?

Comment: umm...it is a good way to do that. He isn't doing any specific exception handling to validate that usage, but that is wildly horrid to say to use only one try/catch or that it isn't a good idiom. He needs to handle each particular exception with specific exception handling, and then it becomes a good use of individual try/catchs. Putting a single catch-all try/catch block around all your code is an absolutely TERRIBLE idiom...I can't believe you would even suggest that to a beginner as if it was a good idea. Suggest to him the right way to handle individual exceptions instead next time please.

Comment: @searchengine27 The code is garbage. It doesn't even compile, and if it did it wouldn't execute: it would fail with an NPE. There are severe logic errors here. He doesn't need to handle each exception individually, and he is making no attempt to actually do so. As for 'suggest to him the right way', I refer you to my answer.

Comment: @EJP what the h**l are you talking about? you are talking about his code as it literally is and I'm talking about the practice he's trying to do. Seriously, please stop commenting if you're going to be a child and throw a fit.

Answer (score 1):

The first `catch` block is missing its argument. That's the `(...)` part that instructs the program about *what* to catch.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Answer (score 1):

Catch statemenents need an Exception to catch.

```
try{
    input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myFile.txt"));
}
catch {
    party = (Event)input.readObject();
    test = (Event)input.readObject();
}
```

It needs to be in the form of

```
try {
// try something
}
catch (Exception e) {
// do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
catch {
```

This is not legal syntax. The `catch` statement requires a `Throwable` argument.

However it's poor code anyway. Don't write code like this. It's pointless. Code that depends on the success of prior code in a `try` block should be inside that `try` block. You only need one `try/catch` here for the main code, and another one in a `finally` block to ensure the closes. And you have code in a `catch` block that shouldn't be there at all. All you need is something like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ObjectInputStream input = null; 

    try{
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myFile.txt"));
        Event party = (Event)input.readObject();
        Event test = (Event)input.readObject();
        System.out.println( party.getName() );
        System.out.println( party.getDate() );
        System.out.println( party.getLocation() );
        System.out.println( party.getDescription() );
        System.out.println( test.getName() );
        System.out.println( test.getDate() );
        System.out.println( test.getLocation() );
        System.out.println( test.getDescription() );
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```